# Convert json string to integer in php

Tags: php, string, int

I'm using xampp and even though I've set the id column as integer in my table, the output is still string i.e I get `"id":"1"` instead of `"id":1`. I've come across a possible solution via `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` but I don't know how to implement this in my php script. Can someone show me how to modify my php script in order to have the id output as an integer.

```
    <?php


    require("config.inc.php");
    $query_params=null;



    $query = "Select * FROM feeds";


    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }


    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


    if ($rows) {
        $response["feed"]   = array();

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $post             = array();
            $post["id"] = $row["id"];
            $post["name"]    = $row["name"];
            $post["image"]  = $row["image"];

            array_push($response["feed"], $post);
        }


        echo json_encode($response);


    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

?>
```

Comment: If you have PHP 5.3.3 then just `json_encode($response, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

Comment: you need to type cast it using (int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json_encode()` goes off whatever PHP says the value's type is:

```
php > $arr = array('id' => '1');
php > var_dump($arr);
array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
php > echo json_encode($arr);
{"id":"1"}
```

Since your `1` is a string in PHP, it'll be a string in JSON as well. So force it to be an int:

```
php > $arr = array('id' => (int)'1');
                           ^^^^^-----note the typecast here.
php > var_dump($arr);
array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
}
php > echo json_encode($arr);
{"id":1}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just add the option to the `json_encode()` call -

```
json_encode( $response, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );
```